# Django - ManyToManyField is not shown in Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I've defined `language_tuples = models.ManyToManyField(LanguageTuple)` in my `UserProfile`. This field should be filled when regular user want to became a translator. So he should be able to choose as many as needed tuples of languages - language by language.

EDIT: Thanks to Shang Wang, now I can choose multiple `LanguageTuples` but I'm not able to create new `LanguageTuple` objects inside the form.

```
class Language(models.Model):
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class LanguageTuple(models.Model):
    language_from = models.ForeignKey(Language, related_name='language_from', null=True)
    language_to = models.ForeignKey(Language, related_name='language_to', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} to {}'.format(self.language_from, self.language_to)
```

So let's assume that there are multiple `Language` objects in database already but no instances of `LanguageTuple`. I want `user` to be able to built his own tuples (as many as he wants). So if there were languages CZ,EN,GE,SK - he can built for example these tuples: CZ-EN, EN-CZ, GE-CZ, SK-GE etc. - after choosing tuples, those tuples are created inside the database as regular `LanguageTuple` instances if does not exists.

The problem is that there is no form field inside the form when it is rendered. Don't know what to do with that... as you can see, I've added field - `language_tuples` into the form.

```
class TranslatorRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    IBAN = forms.CharField(max_length=40,required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40,required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40,required=True)


    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
        'first_name','last_name','IBAN','language_tuples'
        )
```

Comment: I think `TranslatorRegistrationForm` should be a `forms.ModelForm` not `forms.Form`.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks, it helped. But now, I'am able to choose from language tuples but not from languages to became language tuples, do you have any hint?

Answer (score 2):

One problem I've already mentioned in comment that you need `forms.ModelForm` for `TranslatorRegistrationForm`, otherwise django won't recognize all fields you want to display.

If you want user to choose from `language_tuples` as well as creating new pairs, it's going to be 2 forms. One for your existing form, the other is a form for model `LanguageTuple`. You need to display both forms in the template, so people could choose either from the list `language_tuples` or fill out the form for `LanguageTuple`.

Now be aware that you need some logic in place to detect whether user has chosen an existing `language_tuple` or trying to use a newly created `LanguageTuple`. It's some extra steps before you save everything to database but it should be straight forward.